# How can i create and convert json a class with less property in c#?

Tags: c#, json, class

We are developing a c# api project. We want to serialize a class with 3 properties but this class has 10 properties inside it.
How can i create and convert json this class with 3 properties ?
I want to generate a json string with this 3 property.

```
public class SampleClass
{
public string Prop1 { get; set; }
public string Prop2 { get; set; }
public string Prop3 { get; set; }
public string Prop4 { get; set; }
public string Prop5 { get; set; }
public string Prop6 { get; set; }
public string Prop7 { get; set; }
public string Prop8 { get; set; }
public string Prop9 { get; set; }
public string Prop10 { get; set; }
}

var myObj = new MyClass
    {
        Prop1 = "Value 1",
        Prop2 = "Value 2",
        Prop3 = "Value 3"
    };
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what have you tried already? Why it didn't work for you? Could this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `JsonIgnoreAttribute`:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public string Prop3 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prop6 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prop7 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prop8 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prop9 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prop10 { get; set; }
}
```

Reference: [How to ignore properties with `System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties)